# Wordpress and htaccess redirect to another url

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

Struggling with Wordpress and redirects!

I have a wordpress site which is only used (at the moment anyway) to provide url shortening, fangating for Facebook, provide tab pages for Facebook pages etc. i.e. I don't use or want any of the 'normal' Wordpress blog functionality.

To make life easier I want to redirect

```
http://mywordpressurl to https://facebook.com/myfanpage
```

but I don't want to redirect anything else such as

```
http://mywordpressurl/shorturl
```

I need those to be handled normally by Wordpress.

Wordpress has it's existing rewrite rules:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Can I modify these to achieve what I want or can anyone suggest another way of achieving what I want? I've tried... but failed :(

Many thanks!

Comment: `RewriteEngine On` should be alone; remove the `strong text` part.  And it'll only work if you've got `mod_rewrite` active in your Apache config.

Comment: Yes, you're right that was a copy/paste typo in the question. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this ahead of the other rewrite rules:

```
RewriteRule ^$ https://facebook.com/myfanpage [R=301,L]
```